# Identifying Android map markers by position

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this code for dropping a marker on pressing a button on the map. This marker location will be stored in the cloud (own server) and shown to all users of the app. I'm wondering how I should write code to identify a marker in the vicinity and have it removed from the map. I assume this would require some kind of code to be executed persistently?

```
public void dropPacket(LatLng latlng1) {

    CollectibleType t = CollectibleType.MEDIUM_BOX;

    if(temp==null || temp!=latlng1)
    {
        Marker PD = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlng1)
            .title(t.getValue()+" points")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));

        temp=latlng1;
    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot spam packet drops! Please relocate to new position.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    Collectible cl = new Collectible();
    cl.setType(CollectibleType.MEDIUM_BOX.getIndex());
    cl.setDroppedBy(user.getUsername());
    cl.setCollected(Boolean.FALSE);
    cl.setCollectedBy(null);
    cl.setLatitude(latlng1.latitude);
    cl.setLongitude(latlng1.longitude);

    CollectibleService.storeCollectible(cl);

    UserService.itemDropped(user, cl);
}
```

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging? Nah that'd be way overkill if it's a broadcast to *all* users of the app instead of to individual ones, so then you'd need to poll the server.

Comment: Nah, we're using our own server to store the map marker data. I just need a way to recognize that a user is around a marker so he can press the same button to "pick up" (remove) the marker.

Comment: Aah so have you already got code implemented to get the user's current location? I think what you're looking for is Geofencing. Have a look at this training doc: http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Yes. I know there's always the Marker.remove() method. But I'm asking how I can remove a marker simply by it's latitude & longitude values ?

Comment: Well I guess you will have a local list of `Collectible` objects that you are monitoring/displaying on the map. For every object you will have an associated `Marker` and `Geofence`. The `Geofence` ID is created by you so you could just store them all in `HashMap`s against this ID. When a `Geofence` is triggered use the ID to reference the `Marker` to remove it from the map and also to reference the `Collectible` to communicate back to the server.